# Paging effect for the title in iOS nav bar

Tags: ios, ios7, rubymotion

How can I achieve paging the navigation bar title in iOS? That is, having the title in the nav bar slide left or right depending on which way you swipe, fade in/out depending on your swipe and get replaced by the next `UIPageView`'s title.

Twitter's new iOS app does exactly what I am referring to, any thoughts on how this can be  achieved is much appreciated. I have attached a link to an image of Twitters app

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just write a simple demo for you:
https://github.com/singro/SCPaggingNavbar.git

Comment: You have no idea how much time I've spent trying to replicate this. I appreciate your existence.